# How do I know if a item in a grid is selected?

Tags: java, gwt, grid, gxt

Hi i have one problem with my code, I created a grid with a plugin like this:

http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#gridplugins (the second grid)

well now i need know what items are selected when i click in a button. what should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Grid's `GridSelectionModel` (assuming your data is `ModelData`, replace with whatever is appropriate):

```
ModelData item = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

or

```
List<ModelData> items = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```